# display database value as a PHP variable if value is stored in database using prefix $

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named `parameters` where I have inserted a value like '$counter_sales' in one column. Now in my PHP page I have fetched values from that table. When I am trying to echo something like `$row10['column_name']` then it is only giving me result as '$counter_sales' but I want as its value to be displayed which actually I have mentioned for eg. say 12000 in variable `$counter_sales` in above line in same page. Is it possible ? Please help me. Actually want to code like that. In my table `parameters` there is a value '$counter_sales' and  I want to use it like assigned value as mentioned in code.

```
<?php                                                                       
$depart=1;
while($row10 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectedalldepartment))
{
    $sqlsel1 = "select * from parameters ";
    $sqlsel1q = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlsel1);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlsel1q);
    //assigned counter sales value
    $counter_sales  = $row2["counter_sales"];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $depart; ?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;"><?php echo $row10["incentive"] ; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $depaz++;
    $depart++;
}
?>
```

Here is my table:

```
  user_id  |  user_name  |  incentive
     1     | Goldy Shahu | $counter_sales
```

Comment: what you tried?show us your code?

Comment: The manual holds examples, and I suggest you start with a proper API with prepared statements, see this from the manual: [PDO::prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#refsect1-pdo.prepare-examples)

Comment: Even if you are a beginner you need to show some effort, that will show that you are willing to learn, if we give you the answer straight we are denying you an opportunity to learn

Comment: Please edit your question rather than giving additional info in a comment! Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve]!

Comment: see your whole array by `print_r($array_name)` and search what you want to print in the output. Once you find it, than echo that index.

Comment: No actually that is not the case, I have created php variable  $counter_sales already in my php page and now I want to use that variable where I have echo the column value containing $counter_sales. But it is just providing me result as a string only such as '$counter_sales'

Comment: *Stack rule of thumb:* No code=guesswork|no help|no solution.

Comment: Perhaps you saved your variable with the wrong format... you must save his value, don't his name...

Comment: In $selectedalldepartment i have fetched another mysql database table data which I have not mentioned actually ,  where there is my column 'incentive' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [variable variables](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). The problem is that the variable name is expected to be the variable name *without* the dollar sign ($). So you have to use [`ltrim`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) to remove the dollar sign.

Also, you need to surround it with braces and put a dollar sign in front, as explained in the documentation.

So your code to output the variable should look like this:

```
echo ${ltrim($row10['incentive'], '$')};
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much . That is the thing which I was exactly looking for. It has really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Using variable variables is what you need.  Essentially using the contents of one variable as the name of another using `$$`.

Example:

```
$counter_sales = 50; 
$web_sales = 1500;

$results = array('5000', '$counter_sales', '$web_sales', '50');

foreach ($results as $result) {
    if (substr($result, 0, 1) == '$') {     // if first char = '$'
        $var_name = ltrim($result, '$');    // get rid of '$'
        $valueToUse = $$var_name;           // get value from variable with the name of whatever '$var_name' contains
    } else {
        $valueToUse = $result;
    }

    echo "$result --> $valueToUse" . '<br>'; 
}
```

Would yield:

```
//  5000 --> 5000 
//  $counter_sales --> 50 
//  $web_sales --> 1500 
//  50 --> 50
```